# Is there a windows 8 equivalent to NTRights that ACTUALLY WORKS?

Tags: windows-8

I'm trying to give myself the right to log on as a service so I can install a database server as a service. To do that I need the "Log on as a service" advanced privilege because apparently being an administrator is not enough, contrary to the documentation. Installing and running NTRights did not make any difference on Windows 8, so I wonder if there is a Win8 equivalent. Or any other ideas on how to grant this privilege?

Comment: What does "ntrights did not make any difference on Windows 8" mean? ([When you say that something didn't work, you have to say _how_ it didn't work](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100421-00/?p=14283).)

Answer (score 2):

Install your service and then using **services.msc**, change the Log On. When you set the user, **services.msc** will automatically give the Logon As a Service right to that user.

[image]

Alternatively, you can open **Control Panel** -> **Administrative Tools** -> **Local Security Policy** -> **Local Policy** -> **User Rights Assignment** -> *Log on as a service*. Add your user to that setting.

Comment: Hi Ganesh: Thank you for your reply, however services.msc simply opens the window to examine or modify services, it does not give me permission to log on as a service. The Administration Tools window does not include a Local Security Policy option, so that is a dead end as well.

Comment: @user438777 Modify the service and specify the user you want your service to start in. Save it. Automatically on saving services.msc will grant Logon As Service rights to that user